# How to exit a git difftool list in terminal?

Tags: git, vim

e.g.

file `f1`, `f2` and `f3` changed, after press `git difftool`, git would diff the `new f1` and `old f1`.

How to exit `git difftool`?

the `:qa` just exit `diff old.f1 new.f1` only. but I don't want diff file `f2` and `f3`.

my .gitconfig:

`[diff]
      tool = vimdiff`

Comment: For me, quitting difftool brings me back to shell, where it asks if I want to run difftool again, for next files, so I can skip each one that way. I can also ctrl-c after the first file to quit out of it asking if it wants to diff each successive file.

Comment: Given the above comment I would advise you to run `git config --help` and search for `difftool`.